# Why do I need a "create" permission for simple transformations?

Tags: xslt, basex

I am trying to do a simple XSLT transformation in BaseX:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace xslt="http://basex.org/modules/xslt";

xslt:transform-text(<root></root>,
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">123</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
)
```

This works, when running the script as Admin.

But when I run this script with a user that has only "read" permissions, I get the error

```
Stopped at ., 4/20:
[bxerr:BASX0001] create permission required.
```

Why is that? I do not want to store anything in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT transformations can be very powerful. You can e.g. use it to request new resources via fn:doc, or do many more things if you use proprietary extensions. This is the reason why this function was restricted to users with create permission. Restricting it to ADMIN users would probably be even more consistent.

Comment: I see. I have a public REST API, which is read-only. Do you see any way, that a user can get simple, undangerous transformations via this API on-the-fly, without changing its global permissions?

Comment: Maybe I could give the user of the REST API admin rights, but block in Jetty everything except GET requests.

Comment: That would be an option. An other one could be to write your code in RESTXQ, which has by default ADMIN permissions, and do all the specific things you need in XQuery.